# How to arrange code in sublime text using shortcut key?

Tags: sublimetext3

[image]
I want to use shortcut  key for arranging code in the sublime text.

How can I arrange code in sublime text using shortcut key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.

package-install->HTML Beautify then Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F

https://github.com/rareyman/HTMLBeautify

Answer (score 2):

Just add this binding to your "Key Bindings - User" file:

```
{"keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false}}
```

You can also use the "reindent" feature through the command palette.

you can change it from "alt+shift+f" to whatever key you like.
I got this from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/7yxpdw/auto-indenting-on-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps you'd be interested in using a plugin like [Prettify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify)?